# mount.cifs mount error 112 Host is down

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba, cifs

I have a Linux device (running L4T which is based off ubuntu 18.04) running on my local network. From this device I want to mount a shared folder on my win10 laptop. I attempt to do this using the following steps;

- In windows select give access on the folder and give access to everyone
- In linux install cifs-utils (2.7.8) to use mount.cifs
- `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=<myuser> //<laptop-host>/<path> /mnt/backups`
- type all the relevant passwords

My problem is at this point I get error 112 Host is down.

All of the other issues that I have found around this were due to windows no longer using SMB1 and mount failing to negotiate protocols, many people fix this by adding the vers option to force the samba version to use however if I use the vers option I get an invalid argument error.

Furthermore when looking at the manuals for mount.cifs (which for some reason aren't installed on my device) there is no vers option so I'm assuming it was dropped in an update at some point.

`mount -t cifs //<host>/<path> /mnt/backups -o user=<user>, vers=3.0`

**syslog** 
Not much info in here but  ill add the syslog immediately after the failed mount.

```
jackwal@lop-rover:/var/log$ sudo mount -t cifs //DESKTOP-NHJDH1B/Users/Jackr/jetson-backups /mnt/backups
[sudo] password for jackwal:
Password for root@//DESKTOP-NHJDH1B/Users/Jackr/jetson-backups:  ****************
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
jackwal@lop-rover:/var/log$ tail /var/log/syslog
Jan 17 20:00:59 lop-rover systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan 17 20:00:59 lop-rover anacron[14750]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-01-17
Jan 17 20:00:59 lop-rover anacron[14750]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan 17 20:17:01 lop-rover CRON[14831]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 17 21:01:52 lop-rover systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan 17 21:01:52 lop-rover anacron[14952]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-01-17
Jan 17 21:01:52 lop-rover anacron[14952]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan 17 21:17:01 lop-rover CRON[15031]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 17 21:29:29 lop-rover systemd-resolved[3647]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server fe80::e8e:29ff:fe5a:8395%7.
Jan 17 21:29:41 lop-rover kernel: [34152.606730] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112
jackwal@lop-rover:/var/log$
```

I'm about the furthest thing from a sys admin, but my latest project requires a bit more setup, so apologies if it works out there is something obvious I have over looked.

Comment: Can you ping the Windows laptop from the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: @Nasir Yes, can ping. and they can definitely reach each other as I'm using ssh from the laptop to control the Linux machine.

Comment: Does it work if you connect with the IP address? If not, look at `/var/log/messages` on the Ubuntu machine while connecting and add the output to the question.

Comment: @Nasir error is the same over IP and there is no messages log.

Comment: My mistake, the log is `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: All the syslog shows is CIFS VFS failing with -112, but ill add it in now

Comment: When you to mount it with a different SMB protocol and receive and error, what is the syntax that you are using? Add it to your question.

Comment: I have tried it with a whole range of syntax putting spaces around, after or no spaces around the comma, putting the options in various places, making vers the only option. All have given the same error but I have added the most common approach iv seen above. I'm not sure it's so much a syntactical issue as it is that 'vers' isnt a documented option at all

Comment: Follow up to my last comment the documentation does say its possible to send arguments not defined with-in the man if the kernel module supports them. And that unrecognised arguments will be logged in the kern log as we have seen. The module version is 2.09

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around this error by re-enabling SMB1 in Windows:

> Search "Windows Features"
>     Tick the SNB1 box

I am aware there are disadvantages to downgrading to SMB1 however I don't really require the advantages to do a simple backup on a private network and this was the simplest workaround.

(There does not appear to be a direct solution to this so if anyone can solve the issue directly by making Linux use SMB2 that would also be great.)